# Aplicação em c# que coleta dados de uma rede de computadores

Tags: c#, redes, ip

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c# que coleta dados de vários computadores com IPs logicamente diferentes, este acesso está sendo feito ao mesmo tempo e as informações são tratadas na aplicação. No entanto, estou percebendo que o sistema está ficando cade vez mais lento, já tentei enxugar o código, mas desconfio que o erro esteja neste acesso simultâneo dos IPS ( ainda que eu precise destas informações em tempo real, de 14 máquinas). Como posso torná-la mais rápida e mais eficaz?